# 1D matrix data to 2D matrix data (Time series)

Tags: r, matrix, neural-network, time-series

I have this data of currency conversions and I am trying to format the data into a matrix so that I can feed this matrix into a neural network to predict the conversions for the next day. To achieve this, it needs to know the values:
2 days ago, 1 day ago, today, expected which are in this 1D matrix. I am trying to change this 1D matrix into a 2D matrix that I can display the data correctly. I have created a diagram below of how I am trying to format this data but I don't quite understand how to do this, I am new to R programming. I found that the lag() function can be used to create this 'lag' in the data and is used in time series problems but I am not sure how to use it in addition to formatting this data in this format

data format: (2 examples)

[image]

[image]

```
data <-
 structure(
    list(
      `USD/EUR` = c(
        1.373,
        1.386,
        1.3768,
        1.3718,
        1.3774,
        1.3672,
        1.3872,
        1.3932,
        1.3911,
        1.3838,
        1.4171,
        1.4164,
        1.3947,
        1.3675,
        1.3801,
        1.3744,
        1.3759,
        1.3743,
        1.3787,
        1.3595,
        1.3599,
        1.3624,
        1.3523,
        1.3506,
        1.3521
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-25L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

Comment: When posting please cut your data down to a minimal size while retaining enough data to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Sure! I will edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data2` in the Note at the end and assuming it is in ascending order of time we use `flag` (fast lag) to lag it and `na_omit` to omit rows having any NA's, i.e. the first two rows and last row.  They have NA's due to the fact that there cannot be data prior to the start of the series or after the end of the series.

```
library(collapse)

na_omit(flag(data2, 2:-1))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  `L2.USD/EUR` `L1.USD/EUR` `USD/EUR` `F1.USD/EUR`
         <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
1         1.37         1.39      1.38         1.37
2         1.39         1.38      1.37         1.38
3         1.38         1.37      1.38         1.37
```

### Note

```
# input
data2 <- head(data)
```

`data2` looks like this:

```
> data
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  `USD/EUR`
      <dbl>
1      1.37
2      1.39
3      1.38
4      1.37
5      1.38
6      1.37
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The data goes from 2011 to 2013 so not backwards :D. The output you showed, the first two elements in the first row are missing? The first row should have 2 days ago data, 1 day ago , today and then the expected output. Is there anyway you could format it like this? I tried showing it in the diagrams, sorry if it's not clear.